# Unable to search '#' in elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, full-text-search, django-haystack

This query -

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?q=post_text:#test
```

fails to execute with an error

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase
```

with status 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "post_text": "#test"
        }
    }
}'
```

or this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "post_text": "#test"
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: I think it should be **XGET**

Comment: ES will accept either. Some clients won't let you send JSON data with a GET request, though.

Comment: Worked. I have another question. What if I want to get the results of only those documents which contain '#test' and ignore the documents that contain just 'test'.

Comment: You'll probably need to adjust your mapping. There are a number of ways to go about it, but putting [`"index":"not_analyzed"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) in that field in your mapping is probably the easiest, then you can use the term query above. If you want to write up another question I'll write out an example.

Comment: Doing that. Thank you. Here is the link to the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902209/elasticsearch-do-exact-searches-where-the-query-contains-special-characters-lik