# Elasticsearch: do exact searches where the query contains special characters like '#'

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, django-haystack

Get the results of only those documents which contain '#test' and ignore the documents that contain just 'test' in elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People may gripe at you about this question, so I'll note that it was in response to my comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901970/2551686).

You're probably going to want to read up on [analysis in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-analysis.html), as well as [match queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) versus [term queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).

Anyway, the convention here is to use a `.raw` sub-field on a string field. That way, if you want to do searches involving analysis, you can use the base field, but if you want to search for exact (un-analyzed) values, you can use the sub-field.

So here is a simple mapping that accomplishes this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "post_text": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now if I add these two documents:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
    "post_text": "#test"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
    "post_text": "test"
}
```

A `"match"` query against the base field will return both:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "post_text": "#test"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.5945348,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.5945348,
            "_source": {
               "post_text": "#test"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.5945348,
            "_source": {
               "post_text": "test"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

But the `"term"` query below will only return the one:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "post_text.raw": "#test"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "post_text": "#test"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/2f0fbb38e2b7608019b5b21ebe05557982212ac7

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thank you.